# Why are different outputs coming from an array with and without `puts`?

Tags: ruby, arrays, inspect

What is the difference between `puts a1.zip(a2)` and `a1.zip(a2)`? Why do the outputs come out in different way?

```
a1 = %w{a b c}
a2 = %w{1 2 3}

a1.zip(a2)
# => [["a", "1"], ["b", "2"], ["c", "3"]]

puts a1.zip(a2)
# =>
# a
# 1
# b
# 2
# c
# 3
#=> nil
```

Comment: Why is this question getting downvoted? It's actually a very basic and good beginner's question about how the `irb` prompt works. All it needs is a better more generic title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing `puts` in one and just the `zip` call in the other. Why do you expect them to be the same?

`puts` does print each element of an array in its own line, which is what you see here. IRB by default uses `inspect` to print objects. While what you see is different, the output from the `zip` method in both the cases is the same.